# play sound background in while flutter like wifi signal strength, beep

Tags: flutter

good afternoon, permission to ask, I want to play a sound like a metal detector / wifi analyzer in my while (true), with some conditions, for example, less than 50 signal strength means that the object is far away and sounds a sound beep is rarely rare, and if the signal strength is more than 50 then Will the beep play faster because the object is getting closer here has anyone tried it? can the reference, thanks before.